# Screen flickers white after Ubuntu 17.10 upgrade

Tags: display, 17.10, flicker

I just upgraded from Ubuntu 17.04 to 17.10 and after the upgrade the screen flickers a white/grey colour about once a second. It seems to happen more when I move things on the screen. I am running inside VirtualBox. Everything worked fine before the upgrade.

Answer (score 0):

This can be a factor of compositing

we can try to disable vsync in your VM by creating a file in /etc/profile.d

name it say script.sh

export vblank_mode = 0

then logout and login again

see if those white flicks will be gone